# Error when building Next.js project: Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from

Tags: next.js, eslint

I can't `npm run build` my next project it gives me this `Error: Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from`. Referenced:

```
type: 'Error',
  messageTemplate: 'extend-config-missing',
  messageData:
   { configName: 'react-app',
     importerName:
      '/home/kh/development/projects/nextproject/.eslintrc.json' } }
```

and my `.eslintrc.json` file

```
{
  "plugins": ["testing-library", "jest-dom"],
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:testing-library/react",
    "plugin:jest-dom/recommended"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your original build from?

Comment: Try removing `react-app` and `react-app/jest` from the `extends` array. Those are used in Create React App, you don't need them for Next.js projects.